# Error trying to get raw json response from lowlevel elasticsearch nest query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am getting an error from an elasticsearch nest query. I would like to see the raw json response so I can use it to debug. I am trying a very simple query below to get the response as a string but still getting an error. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
        var indices = Indices.Index("my-index");
        var searchRequest = new SearchRequest<string>(indices)
        {
            RequestConfiguration = new RequestConfiguration()
            {
                DisableDirectStreaming = true
            },
            Query = new MatchAllQuery()
        };

        var response = _elasticClient.LowLevel.Search<SearchResponse<string>>("my-index", PostData.Serializable(searchRequest));
```

Error:

> "expected:'String Begin Token', actual:'{', at offset:249"

Answer (score 2):

Response from es is not a string.

Use object instead:

```
var response = _elasticClient.LowLevel.Search<SearchResponse<object>>("my-index", PostData.Serializable(searchRequest));
```

Or if you have your class model:

```
_elasticClient.LowLevel.Search<SearchResponse<yourType>>("my-index", PostData.Serializable(searchRequest));
```

Consider configure the directStreaming on client level:

```
ConnectionSettings connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(
                new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ElasticSearchUrl"]));

            if (debugMode) connectionSettings.EnableDebugMode().DisableDirectStreaming(true);

            _elasticClient= new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. So if I try to cast it to my object, there is a field that is causing an issue I believe, so that is why I wanted to get the raw response without casting to my object, otherwise there is no way for me to figure out where the problem is?

Comment: if <object> work and <yourType> doesnot yes indeed, you need to check mappings / type matching.